# Spawn vim using golang

Tags: go, vim, process, exec

I am trying to run a simple program that spawns a vim process.

The user should be able (when the `exec.Command` starts) to switch to `vim` window and the process execution should halt there.

When user closes `vim` (`wq!`) the program execution should resume from that point.

The following simple attempt fails but I cannot figure out why

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("vim", "lala")

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

```
▶ go run main.go
2022/11/25 09:16:44 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

Why the `exit status 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed these two lines:

```golang
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

Thanks to these two lines the user is able to edit with vim the file in the terminal. The control is returned to the program when the user quit from the terminal (e.g., with the command `:wq`). Below, you can find the whole code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("vim", "lala")

    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because you should set `Stdin` and `Stdout`for `cmd`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("vim", "lala")
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```